# file reading and accessing elements in java

Tags: java, eclipse, file, object

readData.txt contains :
1,1,2,4,8
cloud,44800,40000,100,10000,0,0.01,103,83.25
proxy-server,2800,4000,10000,10000,1,0.0,107.339,83.4333
d_0,2800,4000,10000,10000,1,0.0,107.339,83.4333
d_1,2800,4000,10000,10000,1,0.0,107.339,83.4333
m_0,1000,1000,10000,270,3,0,87.53,82.44
m_1,1000,1000,10000,270,3,0,87.53,82.44
m_2,1000,1000,10000,270,3,0,87.53,82.44
m_3,1000,1000,10000,270,3,0,87.53,82.44
s_0,EEG
a_0,DISPLAY
s_1,EEG
a_1,DISPLAY
s_2,EEG
a_2,DISPLAY
s_3,EEG
a_3,DISPLAY
node[0] contains 1st line(i.e cloud),node[1] contains 2nd line(proxy-server),node[2] contains lines containing d_0,d_1, node[3] contains line containing (m_0 to m_4) and node[4] contains the rest of the lines.

```
static {
    try {
        file = new java.io.File("/home/madhu/Desktop/readData.txt");
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(String.valueOf(file)));
        final String totalNode = reader.readLine();
        final String[] strs = totalNode.trim().split(",");
        nodes = new int[strs.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
            final int a = Integer.parseInt(strs[i]);
            nodes[i] = a;
        }
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void method() {
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes[0]; i++) {
        FogDevice cloud = method1(reader.readLine());
        cloud.setParentId(-1);

        for (int j = 0; j < nodes[1]; j++) {
            FogDevice proxy = method2(reader.readLine());
            proxy.setParentId(cloud.getId())

            for (int k = 0; k < nodes[2]; k++) {
                method3();
            }
        }
}

private static void method3() throws Exception {
    for (int k = 0; k < nodes[3]; k++) {
        method4();
    }
}

private static void method4() throws Exception {
    Sensor s = new Sensor(reader.readLine());
    Actuator a = new Actuator(reader.readLine());
}
```

The above code should follow the sequence like (cloud,proxy-server,d_0,m_0,s_0,a_0,m_1,s_1,a_1,d_1,m_2,s_2,a_2,m_3,s_3,a_3) but it is following the sequence(cloud,proxy_server,d_0,d_1,m_0,m_1,m2_m_3...).While calling method3() it should process node[3] elements. but it is not following.
How to get the above sequence.
Can anyone please help in this ?   Advance thank you.

Comment: Umm, Could you please trim your code to produce a minimal reproducible example(Without your custom classes?) . I see it's basic file parsing problem. Would appreciate if you could elaborate a bit on input and output.

Comment: Hiii.. http://gridbus.csse.unimelb.edu.au/papers/FogApps2020.pdf.  You can see the examples given here. Please help . If I use linked list how it can be rewritten ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to find it at a quick glance. Could you please attach it to question description?

Comment: can you send me your email id.. i will send you my file. i have to submit this tomorrow. @RohanKumar

Answer (score 0):

Your third for-statement calls a method that processed two lines in one call. So instead increment it like:

```
for(int k=0; k<nodes[2];k+=2){
  method3();
```

So your first line in the file specifies 8 lines which instead resemble 4 actuator/sensor-pairs.

Comment: Still showing errors. How to apply Linked list here for multiple list?

Comment: I can't help without a more detailed description of the errors. And there seems to be also e-mail communication I cannot intercept.